# pushing dynamically created dropped elements at the particular position in the dom tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop

Hello people I have a question regarding drag and drop . I am creating an application for creating websites only by using drag and drop . I am kinda stuck implementing a feature in which the user can drop elements at a particular positions and the elements below that dropped element get shifted below . Now the issue is that element is generated dynamically 
for eg . In the right panel there are different components in the form of images and when i drag those elements I pass some meta-data and when the element gets dropped , based on the meta-data an html element is created .

```
<div class="drop-zone">
   <div>
     <!--container 1-->
   </div>
     <!-- now i want to drop that element in between which is generated dynamically -->
   <div>
     <!--container 2-->
   </div>
</div>
```

*****************EDIT*****************************

> In the below code header drop is the directive which will be dragged , JSONfn is same as JSON object used to stringify the functions as well

```
(function(){
define(['../../../../app','./../service/header.factory.js'],function(app){
    app.directive('headerDrop',['HeaderFactory',function(HeaderFactory){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: false,
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
                element.on('dragstart',function(e){
                   e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("data",JSONfn.stringify(HeaderFactory));
                });
            },
            template: "<img id='header' draggable='true' src='/src/create_template/images/noimage.jpg' width='100' height='100'> </img>"
        }
    }]);
    app.directive('dragContainer',function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: false,
            scope: {},
            template: "<div id='elements-container'> <h1 style='text-align:center;'> All </h1><header-drop> </header-drop> </div>"
        }
    });
});
```

})()

> Inside the controller

```
element.on('drop',function(event){
        console.log(event);
        if(event.target.className !== "drop-zone"){
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        var data = JSONfn.parse(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("data"));
        if(data.type=="header"){
            var heading = document.createElement("h1");
            console.log("client height" , heading.clientWidth);
            heading.innerHTML = data.textValue;
            //console.log("pageY",event.pageY);
            //console.log("pageX",event.pageX);
            heading.style.position = "relative";
            heading.style.top = ((event.pageY/window.innerHeight)*100)+ "%";
            heading.className = "editable";
            event.target.appendChild(heading);
            heading.style.top = event.clientY;
            addingEvents();
        }
    });
```

Comment: By "meta-data" are you referencing comment nodes?

Comment: by meta-data i mean data being passed using dataTransfer , and if it is a header that i have to create then i am passing a string "header" and on the basis of data that i pass when i drag an element from component screen i generate the html element

Comment: What is the issue with the code?

Comment: Like i have mentioned the use case is kinda generic, if i have  two divs and i drop an element in between these two divs i want the div to move downward but the problem is I don't know the height of the dropped element until it is created on the dom , so how will i be able to figure out how much the elements are need to be moved.
You can see it is similar to adding an number inside an arrray by dragging and dropping then replace array with the word dom and number with html element

Comment: _"so how will i be able to figure out how much the elements are need to be moved"_ Why do you not perform procudeure when element is appended to DOM?

Comment: I just don't want to only append elements to the drop-zone . I want to able to drop them at any position i prefer . Similar to mailchimp template generator

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Comment: I have added the code . I hope it would be clear cause there is a bit of angular

Answer (score 0):

Well i actually tackled that problem with a naive approach though i found the answer later .

I was making a template generator so this approach worked for me

**Naive Approach**

What i did was , whenever i was dropping the element , i dropped one more block inside the designer of height 5px just above the element kinda like

```
<div class="adjacent-block"> </div> inside css .adjacent-block {min-height: 5px; }
<div class="dropped-block"> </div>
```

Then drop that element inside the adjacent block .

Disadvantage : You have also keep track of the adjacent block

**THE ABOVE METHOD WAS PRETTY PATHETIC AND I WOULDN'T RECOMMEND ANYONE TO DO THAT**

**EASIER AND BETTER APPROACH:**

Inside the dragover event just check if the element is above another element and drop the block before or after the element according to the position of the mouse from the mid of that element .

I haven't implemented this approach but I am pretty sure this would work